# Symfony- FosUserBundle make email nullable not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I am trying to make the email field `nullable`. I've searched here and found to make it `nullable` through attribute override. It worked and on the user database table it is `nullable`. However on the register page when i leave the email field blank i get "**please enter email**"

### User.php

```
 /**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
*
* @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
*     @ORM\AttributeOverride(
*         name="email", 
*         column=@ORM\Column(nullable=true)
*     ),
*     @ORM\AttributeOverride(
*         name="emailCanonical",
*         column=@ORM\Column(nullable=true, unique=false)
*     )
* })
*
*
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
    // ...
}
```

### RegisterFormType.php

```
->add('email', NULL,  array( 'required'   => false, 'label' => false, ))
```

Comment: Need more information - is that an HTML5 validation saying that the email must be entered?

Comment: @JasonRoman yes its an html validation from the fosuserbundle

Comment: Have you checked by removing the `'required'` from array?

Comment: Are you sure you followed all the steps to make sure that your form is actually being used?  There is a whole process to overriding FOSUserBundle forms

Answer (score 0):

Change to this  in the  RegisterFormType.php

```
 ->add('email', LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType'), array( 'required'   => false, 'label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but still getting the error

Comment: I tested and it works try to clear the cache of Symfony and the cache of your browser

Comment: i just  did for both and still didnt work. However, i get this for the legacyformhelper "Referenced entity is marked @internal. This usually means that you are advised to remove the usage or replace it with other construct." when i use use FOS\UserBundle\Util\LegacyFormHelper;

Comment: Or you can change it directly from .twig file that should work

Answer (score 0):

FosUserBundle is using XML for constraints. Create your own file by overriding resources fosuserbundle/resources/config/validation.xml

Comment: I have override the the validation.xml and removed the email part, however still getting validation after i submit the form.